# Yii framework installation

Tags: php

I am new with yii framework. I have downloaded yii-1.1.14.f0fee9.zip file, I extracted and renamed it as yii and placed to my wamp root directory. For creating sample skeleton application, first I created test_project folder in wamp root and then run folling lines to cmd prompt.

cd c:\wamp\www\yii\framework 
 yiic webapp ..\test_project

these lines executed in cmd prompt without error. But, could it see create any sample or skeleton files under test_project folder. I have also tried to run it with browser. It showing blank. Anybody can please help me to start a skeleton project in yii ? Iam really interesting to develop projects in yii. please help me guys.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used wamp but as I see it has a `WWW` directory. You should place your projects in this directory, otherwise it won't be available for browsers. (Never take the framework files here, just leave there than you placed before)

Using `yiic`. It is a command line tools (doesn't work from browser) for making skeleton app, migrations etc.

try:

1. cd (c:....... framework) [enter]
2. yiic webapp c:\......\www\test_project  [enter]

The main are points the `WWW` and the separated command

I guess it will work.

Greg

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps

> 1. cd c:\wamp\bin\php\phpx.x.xx
> 2. c:\wamp\www\yii\framework\yiic webapp c:\wamp\www\test_project

Note that in step 1. is your php directory that has php.exe file

**Update:**

For detail you can have a look at this link http://www.larryullman.com/series/learning-the-yii-framework/

This is a very good tutorial for Yii application initiation.

hope this will help

Comment: I tried these two steps. But nothing happend. After executing these two cmd line now also folder test_project seems to be empty :( . Actually what will happen after executing commands. I, think some yii skeleton files will automatically create under the test_project folder. am I right? Iy yes, how it possible?

Comment: Yes this command will create complete project with models controllers and view and all other yii stuffs.. i would like you see both commandals you execute i hope you didnt execute it with those x.x.xx

Comment: I mean I would like to see both the commands you have run into the terminal. sorry for the weird english..

Comment: Hello, I tried like this, 1) cd D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16 2) D:\wamp\www\yii\framework\yiic webapp D:\wamp\www\test_project

Comment: i see... well it looks good to me, let me see what else you can do

Comment: weird .. did you try opening command prompt as an administrator?

Comment: Can you please give me step by step explanation for creating yii skeleton application. I read lot of articles related to this. But, still now I couldn't start work with yii. I am so sad.. Please help me.

Comment: take a look at this http://www.larryullman.com/series/learning-the-yii-framework/

Comment: hi.. now I have created yii skeleton application successfully. thx for the support.

Comment: nice, by following the above link?